# Using jQuery Selectric with dynamic IDs

Tags: jquery

I am using the [jQuery selectric](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric)) plugin to customize one of my select lists. I turned this select list into a dynamic field that users can add new select select lists now. But when user adds a new select list, selectric plugin does not get initialized because the new select list will have a new `id value`.

While the initial select list id is `#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type`, new select lists have `#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-add-more--2`, `#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-add-more--3` and so on. You can [try it here](http://chakraco.club/node/add/application).

```
// Initialize Selectpick
$('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').Select();

//Bind the click event to button,and trigger the 'set' event of origin element
$('#set_first_option').on('click', function() {
    $('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').trigger('set','app_1_column_layout');
});
$('#set_second_option').on('click', function() {
    $('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').trigger('set','app_1_column_light_gray_bg');
});
$('#set_third_option').on('click', function() {
    $('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').trigger('set','app_2_column_layout');
});
$('#set_fourth_option').on('click', function() {
    $('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').trigger('set','app_2_column_light_gray_bg');
});
$('#set_fifth_option').on('click', function() {
    $('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').trigger('set','app_2_column_green_bg');
});
$('#set_sixth_option').on('click', function() {
    $('#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type').trigger('set','app_3_column_layout');
});
```

Comment: You would need to tie in the initialization of the new select list after the point that it has been added.

Comment: @Efe The posted code is useless.  Where is the event handler for whatever control the user uses to "add a new select list"?  That is where you call `.Select()` on the DOM element added.

Comment: What do you mean, it worked for 1 select list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the triggers to be available for dynamically generated elements you have to use the document selector.

An example could be:

```
$(document).on("click", "#set_sixth_option", function() {
    $("#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type").trigger('set','app_3_column_layout');
});
```

This way the function would work for both existing and dynamically created elements.

What I would recommend though is that if your `set_nth_option` elements do the same job, you should use a class and perhaps a `data-id` attribute to distinguish between each. Something like

```
$(document).on("click", ".set_option", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-type").trigger("set", "app_"+id+"_column_layout");
});
```

Comment: my struggle is with dynamic ID values, I dont know how I could make the function work for all; e.g. `#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-add-more--2`, `#edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-add-more--3`

Comment: I guess this would do it, `"[id^=edit-field-app-paragraphs-und-add-more-add-more--]"`

Comment: I'm going to lose my mind, I put it inside `$(document).on("click", ".paragraphs-add-more-submit` just as you suggested it but still does not work

Comment: Could you update your code with an example HTML structure so that I can see how your structure works? @Efe

Comment: I'm completely lost right now, I removed the plugin, I thought it would work after but could not make it work. Ended up opening another topic, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411633, but no one can seem to help